# customizing tooltip on chart.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I would like to customize the tooltip on a chart.js bar chart. This is my code:

```
$(function () {
  var barData = no_houses_person

var barOptions = {
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,
    scaleShowGridLines: true,
    scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top'
    },
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
    barShowStroke: true,
    barStrokeWidth: 1,
    barValueSpacing: 5,
    barDatasetSpacing: 1,
    responsive: true,
};
   var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
   var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barData,
    options: barOptions
});
});
```

I have tried adding `tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%> <%}%>(<%= value %> example)",` to barOptions but it has no effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chart.js moved from Templates to [Object interfaces](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration) in v2+, so for instance If you just want to modify the tooltip text...

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem) {
            return "$" + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel) + " and so worth it !";
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Codepen: [Chart.js Custom Tooltip](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/OReEKx?editors=0010)

For more complex tooltip customizations see their samples on github: [tooltips](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/docs/samples/tooltip)